# How to get rid of default gray color in drop down list with size attribute?

Tags: html, css, select, drop-down-menu, styles

**When I create a drop down list with size="2", a gray color would appear on the selected option when the DDL is out of focus**.

it's bugging me and I want to change the gray. I tried a lot of things but I can't seem to find a way to remove it, even with jQuery.
Code:

```
<select name="ddl" id="ddl" size="2">
   <option value="kg">Kg</option>
   <option value="gm">Gm</option>
   <option value="pound">Pound</option>
   <option value="MetricTon">Metric ton</option>
   <option value="litre">Litre</option>
   <option value="ounce">Ounce</option>
</select>
```

Note that when size="2" is removed, the gray doesn't show up.

**Any ideas on how to change it?**

Comment: I think that is standard behavior

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7208786/how-to-style-the-option-of-a-html-select

Comment: you can use bootstrap select to cusomize select: https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/examples/